# Aggregation record with left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to aggregate records between two table e.g. below I've tried left outer join with TB_SRS_MST table but I'm getting the desired result. Basically I want to show "-" for every series not exist in TB_DLR_STS table.

**TB_DLR_STS TABLE**

```
 DLR_CD  SRS_CD   STS
    D1    S1        Y
    D1    S2        N
    D2    S2        Y
    D2    S3        Y
    D3    S1        N
```

**TB_STS_MST TABLE**

```
SRS_CD  
  S1    
  S2    
  S3    
  S4
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
DLR_CD  SRS_CD  STS
D1      S1      Y
D1      S2      N
D1      S3      -
D1      S4      -
D2      S1      -
D2      S2      Y
D2      S3      Y
D2      S4      -
D3      S1      N
D3      S2      -
D3      S3      -
D3      S4      -
```

Comment: where is `S4` coming from?

Comment: I'm sorry corrected TB_SRS_MST record

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data in the `TB_STS_MST` table should actually look more like this:

```
SRS_CD  
S1    
S2    
S3    
S4
```

Assuming so, first you need to define your desired list -- you can do this by creating a `cartesian product` with a `cross join`.  Then you can use an `outer join` with `coalesce`:

```
select t.dlr_cd, t.srs_cd, coalesce(ds.sts, '-') sts
from (
   select distinct ds.dlr_cd, sm.srs_cd
   from TB_DLR_STS ds cross join TB_STS_MST sm
) t left join TB_DLR_STS ds on t.dlr_cd = ds.dlr_cd 
                           and t.srs_cd = ds.srs
```

Comment: @user2101952 if this answer solved your problem, could you accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with left partitioned join.

```
select tb_dlr_sts.dlr_cd,
       tb_sts_mst.srs_cd,
       nvl(tb_dlr_sts.sts, '-') as sts
  from tb_sts_mst
       left join tb_dlr_sts partition by (tb_dlr_sts.dlr_cd) on tb_dlr_sts.srs_cd = tb_sts_mst.srs_cd
```